# subfigures caption using overleaf

Tags: graphics, overleaf

I am trying to insert subfigures within figures in an overleaf document.
The problem is that the subfigure’s caption is not centered.

Can someone know how to fix this please?
Thank you in advance

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\section {Scrum roles}
\indent\hspace{0.1in}Scrum has three roles: product owner, scrum master and the development team members. While this is pretty clear, what to do with existing job titles can get confusing. Many teams ask if they need to change their titles when adopting scrum. The short answer is no.
In this section, we’ll define scrum roles. 
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=2.5cm, height=2.5cm, scale=1.1]{figures/master.jpg}
        \caption{Scrum master}
        \label{fig:Scrum master}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=2.5cm, height=2.5cm, scale=1.1]{figures/equipe.jpg}
        \caption{Team}
        \label{fig:Equipe de développement}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=2.5cm, height=2.5cm, scale=1.1]{figures/productowner.JPG}
        \caption{Product owner}
        \label{fig:Product owner}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{The scrum roles}
    \label{fig:The scrum roles}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ ||c|c||}
 \hline
    Product Owner & ensures that they are delivering the most value..\\
    \hline
    Scrum Master & gluing everything together and ensuring that scrum is being done well.\\
    \hline
    Team & The development team are the people that do the work\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Description des rôles dans Scrum}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: The output]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Okay, I will add the full code

Comment: I would suggest using the `subfloatrow` environment` from the `floatrow` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the line you are searching for is `\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}` however just using that would not fit for you as you are hardcoding your image witdh to be 2.5cm in a float object of 0.3/textwidth thus your caption would be centered with the float object but not with the image itself. Here is something that should fit for you aligning both by setting the width of the image to its container :

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,  scale=1.1]{figures/master.jpg}
        \caption{Scrum master}
        \label{fig:Scrum master}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, scale=1.1]{figures/equipe.jpg}
        \caption{Team}
        \label{fig:Equipe de développement}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, scale=1.1]{figures/productowner.JPG}
        \caption{Product owner}
        \label{fig:Product owner}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{The scrum roles}
    \label{fig:The scrum roles}
\end{figure}
```

Also I noticed your tabular goes beyond the width of your text so I suggest using a tabularx with the following :

```
\usepackage{tabularx}

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ ||c|X||}
 \hline
    Product Owner & ensures that they are delivering the most value..\\
    \hline
    Scrum Master & gluing everything together and ensuring that scrum is being done well.\\
    \hline
    Team & The development team are the people that do the work\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

With both snippet in your example, the output is the following  [image]

Comment: That worked for me, thank you so much for your help

Comment: Use `scale 1.1` has no sense ... see my answer! As well of use `\captionsetup` in your solution is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\section {Scrum roles}
\indent\hspace{0.1in}Scrum has three roles: product owner, scrum master and the development team members. While this is pretty clear, what to do with existing job titles can get confusing. Many teams ask if they need to change their titles when adopting scrum. The short answer is no. In this section, we’ll define scrum roles.

With \verb+\centering+ in `\verb+subfigre+ environments:
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=2.5cm, height=2.5cm}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}\centering
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{figures/master.jpg}
        \caption{Scrum master}
        \label{fig:Scrum master}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}\centering
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{figures/equipe.jpg}
        \caption{Team}
        \label{fig:Equipe de développement}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}\centering
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{figures/productowner.JPG}
        \caption{Product owner}
        \label{fig:Product owner}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{The scrum roles}
    \label{fig:The scrum roles}
\end{figure}

or with use of \verb+subfloat+ commands
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=2.5cm, height=2.5cm}
\subfloat[Scrum master]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
                        \label{fig:Scrum master}}
\hfil                       
\subfloat[Team]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
                        \label{fig:Equipe de développement}}
\hfil
\subfloat[Product owner]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
                        \label{fig:Product owner}}
\caption{The scrum roles}
\label{fig:The scrum roles}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ ||l|X||}
 \hline
    Product Owner & ensures that they are delivering the most value..\\
    \hline
    Scrum Master & gluing everything together and ensuring that scrum is being done well.\\
    \hline
    Team & The development team are the people that do the work\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Description des rôles dans Scrum}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Note:**

- In your MWE (Minimal Working Example) sub captions are centered to `subfigure` environment, but images are not (they are left aligned). This can be corrected by adding `\centering` after  `\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}` as is done in above MWE.
- Instead of subfigure environments (in the case that you use recent version of `subcaption` package) you can use `\subfloat` command, which automatically center image and caption. See second example in MWE.

**Off-topic:**

- At defining image size by `[width=2.5cm, height=2.5cm, scale=1.1]`  the `scale option hasn't any effect. It can be dropped as done in above MWE
- Your table id wider than `\textwidth`, consequently it protrude right text area margin. This can be simple prevent by use of `tabularx` table (see MWE)